# What does the error ' this.context.sourceCache ' mean and where does it come from?

Tags: xpages

I have small question regarding the following error:

> this.context.sourceCache

On a custom control I defined a extlib dialog which contains a panel with a document datasource. Sometimes when I submit the form using a simple action (and a dialog.hide('content') I receive this error. I cant seem to find where it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the firebug plugin by any chance, just wondering if it could be related to firebug:

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.4/content/firebug/spy.js?r=2796

It's a long shot, but I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I'm using firebug. I have to investigate it further to be sure it is indeed firebug. But it could be.